# Insurance and car rental in US

Tags: usa, car-rentals, insurance

I'm going to rent a car in California for a week soon and was wondering whether to purchase insurance along with the rental. Some sources, eg [Should I purchase rental car insurance? What protection does my credit card provide?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/435/rental-car-insurance-should-i-purchase-it-what-protection-does-my-credit-card) say I do need it, while a friend of mine claims the agency is by the law obliged to insure you and what you purchase is only additional insurance. I haven't been able to get too much additional information from the place I'm going to rent from. Can anybody give me a more informed answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Americans who drive, carry their own insurance that covers them in any car they drive. If you're not American (or live in New York:-)), you're required to carry at least the minimum liability insurance under the California law. Is it enough for you? The liability is yours, in case of an accident, not theirs.

According to [this site](http://www.best-car-rental-tips.com/california-rental-car-insurance.html), in California rental companies are **not** obliged to provide you the state mandated coverage, and indeed I couldn't find any official reference that such a rule exists (I could only find some claims that it does on various travel forums).  [This discussion](http://www.fatwallet.com/forums/travel-discussion/1182056/) also supports the claim that there's no such obligation.

Credit cards usually provide CDW coverage, not liability insurance.

Comment: though not bulletproof, it still indicates i should probably get some. thank you.

Comment: California, along with a couple other states, does not require any driver to have driver liability insurance. That is why it is not included in the standard package. But it also means if someone hurts/kills you, since he has no insurance you will not be covered. So it is a good idea to get the liability insurance at least.

Comment: *Americans who drive, carry their own insurance that covers them in any car they drive* — Really?  Even if they don't own a car?

Comment: @gerrit especially if they don't own a car. What possible reason would there be for a person without a car to have an insurance coverage if it only covered the car the person doesn't own? In any case, the liability protection is for the driver, not for the car.

Comment: @littleadv I didn't know it was possible to purchase any form of car-related insurance without already owning a car.  Any insurance cost calculators I have seen ask details about the year and the make of the car.  Googling *non-owner car insurance* yields websites explaining the concept, but clicking through to insurer's websites I'm back at places asking me for car details.

Comment: @gerrit I don't know if its possible, you're the one to raise the concept. But if it were - that would obviously be the liability portion only. I would assume that those without a car can have their liability covered with an umbrella policy. As to why the ask details about the car - that's because of the damage/loss portion. That one only covers the car stated in the policy.

Comment: @littleadv I'm confused. You said that Americans who drive carry their own insurance, but now you say that you don't know if it's possible?

Comment: @gerrit I think you confused yourself. Go back and read your original comment again and try to follow the thread.