# What is the minimum age to drive and to rent a car for a trip between Los Angeles and Las Vegas?

Tags: car-rentals, regulations, california, age-limits, nevada

I want to travel from SF to Las Vegas and spend 4 days in LA in the middle. Well I want to rent a car to do all the path, but the following question came to my mind:

What is the minimum age to rent and drive a car in California and Nevada? I am 24.

Comment: In California, I think you need to be 18 to have a non-California license recognized, but most rental agencies won't rent to anyone under 21 by policy.

Comment: and yeah, it sucks but you'll pay the young driver fee until you're 25. I was looking for a company that does not apply this fee to 24-old people, but I couldn't find any so far.

Answer (score 2):

As @waiwai933 said, and it's applicable to most states in the US, you need to be 21 to rent a car. [SmarterTravel website](http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/renting-a-car-under-age-25-is-possible-but-pricey.html?id=1262493) summarizes the issue pretty well. What you need to know is that you'll have to pay $25 to $35 a day as Young Driver Fee at most car rental agencies, with a maximum of $300 (so for rentals over 10 days you don't pay any more for the rest)

Watch for good deals though, I remember I never paid it at Hertz because they often have [a discount for young drivers](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/q-8010640/save-up-to-$25-a-day-if-you-re-20-24-years-old-special-offer). It's written that it's until a certain date but I used the same coupon number a year ago, so they probably extend it every couple months.

If you are under 21, read [SmaterTravel article](http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/renting-a-car-under-age-25-is-possible-but-pricey.html?id=1262493), as they say there are few offers but it becomes very pricey.

If you don't rent, I don't know what's the law in America. 16? 18?

By the way, a useful fact is that [in California liability insurance is not mandatory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8834/insurance-and-car-rental-in-us). It means if you don't ask for it at the time of rental, if you hurt/kill someone in an accident, you'll have to pay all of the hospital fees.

Comment: Global to the USA? (-: Is that like being nation-wide to the world?

Comment: I updated the post.